# XSLT: generate-id() and 2 equal arguments

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT 2.0:

@ Linenumber 8370 this code:

```
<TestCaseElement>
            <Name><![CDATA[DUT_AC_ON]]></Name>
            <TaggedValues>
            </TaggedValues>
            <Description>
                <Line><![CDATA[{TEXT_LANG} DUT AC ON]]></Line>
                <Line><![CDATA[{TEXT_ENGL} DUT AC ON]]></Line>
            </Description>
            <ModelingToolID><![CDATA[EAID_E9ACC0C9_D383_4ef0_99FF_F87C90BDF43C]]></ModelingToolID>
            <Hash><![CDATA[1238228468]]></Hash>
            <ID><![CDATA[1115]]></ID>
            <Stereotypes>
                <Stereotype><![CDATA[StepStart]]></Stereotype>
            </Stereotypes>
            <Role><![CDATA[TESTSTEP]]></Role>

</TestCaseElement>
```

and later in the XML-Document the same *ModelingToolID*

Here is an external Link to the picture to visualize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOFNz.png

I generate ID's with this XSL-Code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement/ModelingToolID[  
 ( not( ../Stereotypes ) or ( ../Stereotypes/Stereotype != 'Precondition' and
  ../Stereotypes/Stereotype != 'Postcondition' ) ) and 
 (../Stereotypes/Stereotype = 'StepStart') and 
 ( ../Role = 'TESTSTEP' or ../Role = 'VP' )  and 
 ../Description and 
 ( generate-id() = generate-id( key( 'ModelingToolID', .)[ 1 ] ) ) ]">
```

You see in Linenumber 8370 and 10296 two identic ModelingToolID's. 
I need both TestCaseElements in my Transformation and in my desired output.
But, understandably, only the first will be taken. 
What can i do to get both TestCaseElement's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You see in Linenumber 8370 and 10296 two identic `ModelingToolID`'s. 
>   I need both TestCaseElements in my Transformation and in my desired
>   output.  But, understandably, only the first will be taken.  What can
>   i do to get both TestCaseElement's?

The function `key()` (without a predicate appended to it) by definition produces a node-set of nodes, each having the same key as the second argument.

**Therefore, inside the `xsl:for-each` instruction you need:**

```
key( 'ModelingToolID', .)
```

This selects *all* nodes that match the match pattern in the `match` attribute of the `xsl:key` named `"ModelingToolID"` -- exactly what you want to obtain.

**You can use this expression in various XSLT instructions**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vGroup" select="key( 'ModelingToolID', .)"/>
```

**Or**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key( 'ModelingToolID', .)">
  <!-- Process the group here  -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Ok, great answer. I do not 100% understand why - but this is the solution. :-). Thank you very much.